# Why exception throws while closing the connection?

Tags: java, orientdb

I'm tring to use [orientdb](http://code.google.com/p/orient/). The sample is very simple:

```
package models;

import java.util.List;

import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.object.ODatabaseObjectPool;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.object.ODatabaseObjectTx;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery;

public class User {

    public String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String uri = "local:c:\\orientdb";

        ODatabaseObjectTx db = ODatabaseObjectPool.global().acquire(uri, "admin", "admin");
        db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(User.class);

        User user = new User();
        user.name = "aaa";
        db.save(user);

        List<?> list = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery<Long>("select count(*) from User"));
        System.out.println(list);
        db.commit();
        db.close(); // ****** throws exception
    }
}
```

But the last line `db.close()` will throw an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.common.concur.lock.OLockException: Can't release a database URL not acquired before. URL: c:\orientdb
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolAbstract.release(ODatabasePoolAbstract.java:81)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolBase.release(ODatabasePoolBase.java:43)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.object.ODatabaseObjectTxPooled.close(ODatabaseObjectTxPooled.java:81)
    at models.User.main(User.java:26)
```

Where is wrong?

Comment: what does db.isClosed() return after the commit() ?

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy, I found it a bug of orientdb. See my answer

Comment: I encountered the same thing when I was using database with java and I got the exception because there's a chance that the connection isn't even established. So, the connection can't be closed without getting started hence an exception. I guess there gotta be an error while establishing a connection using the windows path in OrientDB as I find the Freewind's comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found it a bug of Orientdb. It can't handle windows path correctly, and not provide good error messages.

If I use `local:c:/orientdb` not `local:c:\orientdb`, everything is fine.

I have reported this to orientdb team.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this!  Just came across the same bug.